# VSTS Build Pipeline: set variable value before queue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Build Pipeline: VSTS and Repo: VSTS

I am trying to create VSTS build pipelines for two branches Dev and UAT. I can achieve it by creating two different pipelines but since both has almost  similar steps so I wanted to have only one pipeline and depending on condition I can omit some steps. But I am not able to figure out how to pass the variable value(branch which triggered the build) before queueing the build in VSTS.

Background: I tried to get both branch source, setted triggers on both branch and use Build.SourceBranchName variable but it is giving value the top level(Project) value instead of branch name. I have structure like below

Project
- Dev
- QA

The agenda is to trigger the build pipeline on checkin, sanity checks an publish the artifacts as per the environment(Dev,QA). I am not going for CD right now (will be handled manually because of some constraints).

The solution might sound very awkward but I am a newbie and I want to learn it.

I have checked some people have explained through API but any way to do through UI?

[VSTS use API to set build parameters at queue time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838651/vsts-use-api-to-set-build-parameters-at-queue-time)

Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image]
￼[image]

Comment: try investigating the Variables Tab. It is between the Tasks and Triggers Tab.

Comment: Build.SourceBranchName should works. Are "Dev" and "QA" branches in your repo? Or they are just folders?

Comment: Dev & QA are branches in my repo under Yomail folder

Comment: Did you add the mapping for these two branches under "Get Sources" settings?

Comment: Yes, in the first snapshot I have shown the same.

Answer (score 0):

To add a variable that you can pass the value when you queue the build you need to go to `variables` tab, then add your variable and check the checkbox `Settable at queue time`.

[image]

Now when will queue a build you can change the default value.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I hope you are not talking about manual queue. Can you please tell me how to set a value of variable when code is commited. Build needs to get triggered when somebody commits code in the branch.