# Pass different parameter value to Azure DevOps Pipeline based on schedule

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a long-running DevOps pipeline that sets up a complex environment every morning.

It has a parameter; let's call it "*Version*."

I need to schedule the pipeline to run three times each morning with *Version* values 1, 2, and 3 automatically.

Looking through the triggers, neither a schedule trigger nor a pipeline trigger seems to allow to pass a parameter value.

Is there a way to do that? 
Important is that they run independently of each other. Each execution takes between 30 and 60 minutes. So running them in a loop one after each other is **not** an option.

---

This is what my YAML code currently looks like:

```
trigger: none
pr: none
schedules:
  - cron: 0,5,10 12 * * mon,tue,wed,fri
    displayName: Scheduled most mornings
    branches:
      include:
      - CIBranch
    always: true

parameters:
- name: Version
  type: string
  default: '3'
```

Comment: Each morning you want to run all three versions?

Comment: Yes, Krzysztof Madej. Every morning all three, once each.

Comment: updated, @leo-liu-msft

Comment: @SebastianMeine, I have provided a workaround, would you please check if it helps?

Comment: Azure DevOps still does not allow passing parameters to scheduler-triggered jobs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Devops Build: parameters for scheduled builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893621/azure-devops-build-parameters-for-scheduled-builds). The [Azure documentation suggests to exploit the `displayName` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#buildcronscheduledisplayname-variable) to achieve schedule specific behavior. (But in this specific use case a matrix is better suited I guess.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While passing different parameters seems not possible, there is a way to achieve this.

In the yaml file, use the strategy section like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

strategy:
  matrix:
    Run1:
      myvar: 12
    Run2:
      myvar: 14
    Run3:
      myvar: 16
```

This will create three "runs" setting `myvar` as an environment variable.

See [Azure DevOps / Azure Pipelines / Pipeline basics / Jobs & stages / Define container jobs # Multiple Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#multiple-jobs) for details. (Note: While this documentation talks about containers, this works without containers as well.)

Comment: How do you combine strategy with schedules? Lets say I need to have a variable "isScheduledRun" enabled only for scheduled runs, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run three times the same build changing just a parameter, you shoudl consider moving main steps to template. It may look like that:

```yaml
#template.yaml
parameters:
- name: 'Versions'
  type: object
  default: {}
- name: 'server'
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
- ${{ each version in parameters.Versions }}:
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.server }}:${{ version }}
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.server }}:${{ version }}
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.server }}:${{ version }}
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.server }}:${{ version }}
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.server }}:${{ version }}
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.server }}:${{ version }}
```

Build definition:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none
schedules:
- cron: 0,5,10 12 * * mon,tue,wed,fri
  displayName: Scheduled most mornings
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- template: template.yaml
  parameters:
    Versions: 
    - "1"
    - "2"
    - "3"
    server: someServer
```

Comment: Thanks, @krzysztof-madej. It seems you are suggesting to run the job steps in a loop. I am not sure why I would need a template for that. But, independent of that, a loop would stretch out the total run time too far. So it is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 0):

> Pass different parameter value to Azure DevOps Pipeline based on schedule

I am afraid there is no such out of box way to achieve this.

As workaround, you could try to use Azure DevOps counter to set the version from `1-3` for each scheduled build, like:

```
variables:
  internalVersion: 1
  semanticVersion: $[counter(variables['internalVersion'], 1)]
```

Then we could create powershell scripts to determine whether the `counter` value is equal to `3`, if so, call the REST API [Definitions - Reset Counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/reset%20counter?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) to reset the counter variable Value and return the seed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to handle this limitation by Azure Dev Ops is to create a kind of new "wrapper" build pipeline that triggers parameterized your desired build pipeline by using this custom build task "[Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks)". This task allows you to trigger builds with parameters and offers a few more trigger options. You can schedule the "wrapper" build as you now it and create a task for each desired parameterized build to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use loop on stage or job and still achieve desired outcome

```
trigger: none
pr: none
schedules:
  - cron: 0,5,10 12 * * mon,tue,wed,fri
    displayName: Scheduled most mornings
    branches:
      include:
      - CIBranch
    always: true

parameters:
- name: Version
  type: string
  default: '1,2,3'

stages:
  - ${{ each version in split(parameters.Version, ',') }}:
    - stage: Running_For_${{ version }}
      displayName: 'Running - ${{ version }}'
      dependsOn: []
      jobs:
        - job:
          steps:
            - script: echo "Hello World"
```

`dependsOn: []` to run all your stages in parallel.