# Azure Pipeline Trigger Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines

I have two YAML pipelines A and B, where A triggers B. They both have same parameter P. Pipeline B has set resource trigger and is run after pipeline A finishes - this works. However it seems that pipeline B is not run using the same parameter P as pipeline A is. B uses always default (first) parameter.
I have tried finding a solution to pass parameters from A to B, without success. I found some older (2020) similar question, where there is stated it is not possible.
Is this something that cannot be done (using resource triggers) or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

*As per the [So](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61744873) thread answer return by MSFT you can't pass different parameter values to pipeline triggers.*
*And you can follow the workaround provided by the same MSFT that using DevOps counters.*

```yaml
variables:
  internalVersion: 1
  semanticVersion: $[counter(variables['internalVersion'], 1)]
```

*for more information of DevOps counters check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/reset-counter?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1).*

*You can even raise a [feature request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/search.html?type=question%20OR%20idea%20OR%20kbentry%20OR%20answer%20OR%20topic%20OR%20user&redirect=search/search&sort=relevance&q=Pass%20different%20parameter%20value%20to%20Azure%20DevOps%20Pipeline%20based%20on%20schedule).*

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answer. I think that's the post I mentioned. But it's been two years and one would think such a feature would be implemented already. Anyway counter isn't a very clean solution for my use case. I could definitely use other workarounds.

Comment: Even now this feature is not available along with using alternate work arounds if you could also raise a feature request that could help the other members as well.