# How to trigger Azure devops pipeline from different project within same organization using stage/resource?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to trigger a Test pipeline from a stage of Main pipeline, both the pipelines are present in different projects within the same organization. I am able to trigger the pipeline using the resource option but the problem is it triggers the Test pipeline when Main pipeline finishes successfully but I want to trigger the Test pipeline in between run of Main pipeline using an stage. Is it possible to achieve this using any feature of Azure Devops?

For now I am adding this resource in Test pipeline yaml to trigger after Main pipeline.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Test-Repo 
    source:  Test # Test pipeline from different project
    project: private 
    trigger: true # enable the trigger
```

Comment: Hi @dekode , I am writing to check whether you have tested my post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can trigger the needed build through REST API. Check this: [Powershell to trigger a build in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55461216/powershell-to-trigger-a-build-in-azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is using Extension "Trigger Build Task": https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&targetId=ca4e4e67-3099-4c62-9ea9-bef80e0cc70a&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList

My main Pipeline is in Project A with two stages:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:

    - stage: A
      displayName: A stage
      jobs:
      - job: A
        displayName: A
        steps:
          - task: TriggerBuild@4
            inputs:
              definitionIsInCurrentTeamProject: false
              tfsServer: '{Org URL}'
              teamProject: '{Project B Name}'
              buildDefinition: '213'
              queueBuildForUserThatTriggeredBuild: false
              ignoreSslCertificateErrors: false
              useSameSourceVersion: false
              useCustomSourceVersion: false
              useSameBranch: false
              waitForQueuedBuildsToFinish: false
              storeInEnvironmentVariable: false
              authenticationMethod: 'Personal Access Token'
              password: '{PAT}'
              enableBuildInQueueCondition: false
              dependentOnSuccessfulBuildCondition: false
              dependentOnFailedBuildCondition: false
              checkbuildsoncurrentbranch: false
              failTaskIfConditionsAreNotFulfilled: false
    
    - stage: B
      displayName: B stage
      dependsOn: A
      jobs:
      - job: 
        steps:
        - bash: echo "B"
```

[image]

[image]

Run Main Pipeline in Project A:

[image]

Test Pipeline in Project B is triggered at Main Pipeline Stage A:

[image]

Test Pipeline in Project B.

[image]